# Importing PCAP into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, tshark

I'm trying out `Elasticsearch` for the very first time.

I've downloaded `Elasticsearch` and `Kibana` and everything seems to run fine. I can visit `http://localhost:5601` and view `Kibana` without errors.

I've made some traces with `wireshark`/`tshark` and converted it into `Elasticsearch` format with:

```
tshark -r test_trace.pcap -T ek > test_trace.pcap.json
```

Now I'm trying to import that `.json` into `Elasticsearch`, but it seems to fail:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST "localhost:9200/foo/_bulk" --data-binary "@/Users/test-elastic/test_trace.pcap.json"
```

I'm getting no errors or any output, but visiting `Kibana` shows `index_not_found_exception` and running:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/foo/_search/?size=10&pretty=true'
```

Outputs

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id" : "foo",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "foo"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "foo",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "foo"
  },
  "status" : 404
}
```

How can I import my data correctly and view it in `Elasticsearch` and `Kibana`?

The JSON file is 195MB, converted from 10MB `PCAP` file.
Output of first lines in json-file is:

```
{"index" : {"_index": "packets-2019-02-15", "_type": "pcap_file", "_score": null}}
{"timestamp" : "1549540104875", "layers" : {"frame": {"frame_frame_interface_id":...
```

**UPDATE**

After removing `-s` in `curl` I'm getting output:

```
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
```

Now I've tried to use `split` to split the files into mulitple smaller files.

Testing import again now gives me multiple errors with:

```
..."reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Duplicate field 'ip_ip_addr'\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@5d2f82db; line: 1, column: 1300...
```

**UPDATE**

I used the following command on my `test_trace.pcap.json` to get smaller files:

```
split -l 10000 -a 10 test_trace.pcap.json.pcap.json ./tmp/test_trace.pcap
```

Then I got lots of files and tested import wit the first file:

```
./tmp/test_trace.pcapaaaaaaaaaa
```

The file type in my `.json` is:

```
"frame_frame_protocols": "sll:ethertype:ip:sctp"
```

and there are indeed multiple `ip_ip_addr` fields, as I have source and destination ip addresses in the traces.

Comment: Can you also show the first few lines of `test_trace.pcap.json`? and how big is this file?

Comment: Of course, done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file already contains the index into which the data is supposed to be indexed, i.e. `packets-2019-02-15`, so your query should simply be:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/packets-2019-02-15/_search/?size=10&pretty=true'
```

However, I doubt that you can send a 195MB file in one go, I suggest you [split it and load it in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655401/elasticsearch-data-binary-ran-out-of-memory/32676238#32676238)

Comment: Ok, running `curl 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/packets-2019-02-15/_search/?size=10&pretty=true'` gives me nothing. Won't an error be reported if file is to big?

Comment: The file is probably too big and if you wait long enough you'd probably get a 5xx error. Did your curl bulk command finish executing or did you kill it?

Comment: The `curl` finishes within a few seconds, no error and no need to kill it.

Comment: Hmmm, a few seconds for 195MB sounds weird... can you remove the -s switch?

Comment: any more feedback here?

Comment: How do I remove the -s switch ?

Comment: from your curl command where you bulk upload, simply remove the `-s` switch and replace it with `-v`

Comment: Ah, now I'm getting `HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large`. Perfect thank you. I'll update the post with information and output after using `split`.

Comment: May I ask how you did the split? the split operation is simply suppose to partition your big bulk file into smaller ones. Does each of the split file have a command and document line for each document?

Comment: Used `split -l 10000 -a 10 test_trace.pcap.json /tmp/test_trace.pcap`

Comment: You need to show how you adapted my split script to your case, please update your question with it, so we have a full picture.

Comment: Just testing if https://ask.wireshark.org/question/505/deduplication-in-tshark-t-ek/ might be my issue.

Comment: Well, indeed, if the generated JSON has multiple duplicate fields, it's going to be an issue as it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Ok, now things work with updated Wireshark. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!